# NetLogo 5.2 - hide the halo

Tags: netlogo, halo

I'm using the "mouse-down?" code. 
The problem is that whenever user clicks on a turtle the halo appears. I want to get rid of the halo, or at least hide it.

Please help me to get rid of the halo or hide it.
Thank you
Asnat Zohar

[objects with halo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLmWd.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `reset-perspective` command undoes the effect of any `follow`, `watch`, or `ride` command. So inserting a call to `reset-perspective` in the appropriate place in your code should do the trick.

entry for `reset-perspective` in the NetLogo dictionary: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-perspective

Comment: Hi,In the "Mouse drag one example" in the Code Examples folder, the same problem is observed.  
If you press setup and go, and then click on a turtle - it gets a halo, and you can drag it. 
We tried the "reset-perspective" but it doesn't work.  
We tried a workaround by saying: if subject = nobody [reset-perspective] but that doesn't remove the halo.


Does anybody have other ideas of how to get rid of the halo, at least while not dragging?
Another option: Is it possible to paint the halo in black?

Thank you, Sharona and Asnat

Comment: Mouse Drag One Example ought to call `display` after `reset-perspective`. With tick-based updates, the view won't update without `tick` or `display`. I've reported the bug in the model at https://github.com/NetLogo/models/issues/382